# Quadratic equality constraints via SDP

Tags: optimization, semidefinite-programming, qcqp

I want to know if it is possible to solve a QCQP problem with quadratic equality constraints in SDP. I know it is possible to convert a QCQP to an SDP by using the Shur complement. The following worked for me thus far:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cccccc}
\underset{x}{\min} & x^{T}Q_{0}x+q_{0}^{T}x+c_{0} &  & \underset{t,x}{min} & t\\
s.t & x^{T}Q_{i}x+q_{i}^{T}x+c_{i}\leq0 & \Longleftrightarrow & s.t & \left(\begin{array}{cc}
I & M_{0}x\\
x^{T}M_{0}^{T} & -c_{0}-q_{0}^{T}x+t
\end{array}\right) & \succeq0\\
 &  &  &  & \left(\begin{array}{cc}
I & M_{i}x\\
x^{T}M_{i}^{T} & -c_{i}-q_{i}^{T}x
\end{array}\right) & \succeq0\\
 & i=1,2,\dots,m &  &  & i=1,2,\dots,m & 
\end{array}
\end{equation}
$$

where $M_{j}M_{j}^{T}=Q_{j}$ (eigendecomposition can also be used, thanks Alt)

However it seems this only applies to quadratic inequality constraints.

I considered converting the desired inequality constraints to equalities by using slack variables but I think that technique only works with linear constraints.
I also considered having two constraints like:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
x^{T}Qx+q^{T}x+c\leq0\\
-(x^{T}Qx+q^{T}x+c)\leq0
\end{array}
\end{equation}
$$
To force an equality but the second constraint is not convex so it wont work.

So is there another way to do it?

Edit: turns out quadratic equality constraints are non-convex thus cant be solved directly with this approach

Comment: By Schur, should $Q_j=M_j^TM_j$? or $Q_j=M_jM_j^T$?

Comment: Where are the quadratic equality constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You don't need the constraints $M_{j}M_{j}^{T}=Q_{j}$. For example if $UDU^T$ is the eigen decomposition of $Q_j$, Then $M_j=UD^{\frac{1}{2}}$ (if $Q_j$ is symmetric)

Note that if you introduce new variable $M_j$, then the bilinear forms in the constraints make your problem non-convex, (Besides the fact that equality constraints with quadratic  form  $M_{j}M_{j}^{T}=Q_{j}$that you have to  add also makes the problem non-convex.)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Using the eigen decomposition instead of Cholesky might allow me to Decompose $-Q_i$, problem was that $Q_i$ was positive definite so $-Q_i$ was negative definite and Cholseky cant decompose that. However to clarify though, I dont mean that $M_jM_j^T=Q_j$ is a constraint but rather a once off operation I perform when converting from the QCQP to the SDP (I will edit to clarify).

Comment: >  equality constraints with quadratic form $M_jM^T_j=Q_j$ that you have to add also makes the problem non-convex.
Thank you, with that hint and [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/w8/iisi/ilog/cplex100/usrcplex/solveQCP2.html) I realized that quadratic equality constraints are non-convex thus cant be solved directly, but perhaps relaxation technique can be used to solve such a problem.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot see why you should convert a QCQP in an SDP problem. You may want instead to move to a SOCP formulation, which is usually more robust and enjoy a simpler duality theory.

Solvers for QCQP are far more efficient and reliable than SDP ones.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I didnt ask about the merits/demerits of SDP.

Comment: I was just wondering the reason, out of my curiosity.

Comment: By the way, a quadratic equality is not convex by definition...if I am not wrong you can only get a convex SDP relaxation. I suggest you to search for the sensor network localization problem, there are some SDP relaxations of contraints of the form ||x-y||^2 = z that might be useful.